# Recorrer datos de un datagridview y verificar cual se repite más

Tags: c#, windows-forms, lista, datagridview

Muy buenas estimados, tengo un problemita y no encuentro la lógica para solucionarlo.
He estado realizando un programa en c# windows form, que se trata de ingresar información de un jugador (ID, nombre, edad, etc...) en una lista; ahora bien si el jugador marca un punto yo lo envió a guardar en una datagridview el ID del jugador que marco el punto, el problema se me presenta es que quiero al final del partido por decirlo así, quiero saber quien fue el jugador que marco mas puntos. En mi mente había pensado en un foreach que recorriera toda la columna del ID y fuera verificando cual es numero de id que se repite mas para luego mostrarlo en algún label, pero en mi bloqueo no encuentro la lógica para la comparación.

Aqui tengo el evento del boton donde agrego al jugador que marco el punto

```
private void btt_Marcar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int indice = dgv_tablanotar.Rows.Add();

        dgv_tablanotar[indice].Cells[0].Value = cmb_idjugador.Text;
        
    }
```

No hay nada especial, solo agrego los ID de los jugadores que vayan anotado a mi datagridview llamada "dgv_tablanotar". Ocupo un combobox llamado "cmb_idjugador" que al abrirlo muestre todo los id de los jugadores almacenados en la lista, para solo seleccionarlo al momento que uno marque un punto y añadirlo al datagridview "dgv_tablanotar". Obviamente pondré un botón que sea para mostrar esas estadísticas por decir algo.

Quedo atento a su respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de Hashtable que te permite crear una lista [key,value] de la siguiente forma:

```
// Creamos nuesto hashtable
Hashtable HT = new Hashtable();
// Añadimos nuestro jugador y los puntos
HT.Add(cmb_idjugador.Text, 0);
```

Cuando quiera ir agregando los puntos que lleva un jugador bastaría con hacer un método que vaya sumando los puntos y además podemos aprovecharlo para que si no existe el jugador en nuestro Hashtable pues lo añada, sería así:

```
public void AddPointsToPlayer(string p_ID, int p_Points)
{
   if (HT.ContainsKey(p_ID)) // Si lo tenemos en el Hashtable sumamos los puntos
   {
        HT[p_ID] = Convert.ToInt32(HT[p_ID]) + 1;
   }
   else                      // Si no, añadimos el jugador y los puntos
   {
        HT.Add(p_ID, p_Points);
   }
}
```

Por último basta que recorras tu datagridview y que en dicho bucle vayas haciendo la llamada pertinente al método creado. Al final tienes un Hashtable con toda la información que precisas y accedes de forma directa al valor pasándole la clave que en este caso es el ID del jugador.